# use promise to get only portion of ajax response

Tags: angularjs

The tutorial and docs show this very convenient syntax for AJAX calls:

```
$scope.myvar = $resource(/*blah blah*/);
```

Is there a way to use this syntax (instead of having to create a new `successfn` every time) if my API doesn't return `myvar` but something like `{"myvar": myvar}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: Ah, now I think I got what you're after: You want to have the empty reference (placeholder) for a field of the returned object, in a call like this:

```
var User = $resource('/user/:userId', {userId:'@id'});
```

Am I right?

If so - I think the easiest way is simply to bind to the object's field (aka {{user.myvar}}).

---

Well, the success function is called only once (and if) the data has been received successfully. The function is called with the fetched data given to it as an argument and you can access it no matter its structure. You can reuse a function instead of defining one inline, of course.

So instead of this (example from Angular docs):

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: '/someUrl'}).
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }).
  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

You can use:

```
function myHandler(data) {
     // Do something with data.myvar ...
}

$http({method: 'GET', url: '/someUrl'}).success(myHandler);
```

Hopefully this helps, but very possibly I did not get what exactly you're after :) Let me know.

[Relevant documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http).

Comment: Yes, the reference thing was what I was going after—do you have any other ideas?

Comment: You can create an empty reference (e.g. as a scope member) and update it with the received  data.myvar from your own handler. In other usages I'm afraid I don't immediately see a way to lose the need to reference the myvar member.

Comment: An important point is that Angular resource uses angular.copy() to copy the contents of the incoming data to the existing reference. This means all the existing members of the destination variable are deleted - this is problematic in case you'd like to keep a reference to the member directly (not as an angular expression), hence my suggestion in the answer. (From angular.copy docs: If a destination is provided, all of its elements (for array) or properties (for objects) are deleted and then all elements/properties from the source are copied to it.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to call get() or query() on your resource to make an actual AJAX request.  If you don't want to assign the full result of the server API directly to some ($scope) variable, then you have to write the success function.

```
var SomeResource = $resource('/blah/blah');
var theResource = SomeResource.get({optional params here}, function() {
    $scope.myVar = theResource.myVar;
}
```

or

```
var SomeResource = $resource('/blah/blah');
SomeResource.get({optional params here}, function(theResource) {
    $scope.myVar = theResource.myVar;
}
```

Or do what @Chasseur recommends -- assign the full result then bind to the appropriate field in your view:

```
var SomeResource = $resource('/blah/blah');
$scope.theResource = SomeResource.get({optional params here});
```

Then in HTML use `{{theResource.myVar}}`.

Also, $resource, unlike $http, does not return a promise.  **Update**: in newer versions of Angular, $resource now exposes a promise.